# looping back to a main menu in python

Tags: python, loops

I am making a texted based  game on python 3.3. this is the start to my code:

```
while True:

  print ("You must answer all questions in block capitals")
  print ("Welcome to maze runner")
  print ("To learn about the controls press C")
  print ("To learn the about the different types T")
  print ("To play press START")
  run = input ()
  #Controls
  if run == "C":
     print ("To attack press H")
     print ("To walk forward press W")
     print ("To turn left press A")
     print ("To turn right press D")
     print ("To turn around press S")
     print ("To block press B")
     print ("To open stats press Q")
     print ("To open this screen press C")
     print ("To close this screen press C")
  #Types
  if run == "T":
    print ("Soldier. Press S for more info")
    print ("Archer. Press A for more info")
    print ("Mage. Press M for more info")
    print ("Changeling. Press C for more info")
    print ("Rouge. Press R for more info")
    print ("Press M to go to main menu")
    type_info = input()
    if type_info == "M":
       break
    #Solider info
    if type_info == "S":
       print ("Soldier: Good at close combat")
       print ("         Weak at long range combat")
       print ("         Average speed")
       print ("         Average blocker")
       print ("Press M to go to main menu")
       return_to_menu = input()
       if return_to_menu == "M":
          break      
    #Archer info
    if type_info == "A":
       print ("Archer: Weak at close combat")
       print ("        Good at long range combat")
       print ("        Good speed")
       print ("        Average blocker")
       print ("Press M to go to main menu")
    #Mage info
    if type_info == "M":
       print ("Mage: Weak at close combat")
 print ("      Good at long range combat")
       print ("      Average speed")
 print ("      Good blocker")
       print ("Press M to go to main menu")
    #Changeling info
    if type_info == "C":
       print ("Changling: Average at close combat")
       print ("           Average at long range combat")
       print ("           Average speed")
       print ("           Average blocker")
       print ("Press M to go to main menu")
    #Rouge info
    if type_info == "R":
       print ("Rouge:  Average at close combat")
       print ("        Average at long range combat")
       print ("        Good speed")
       print ("        Good blocker")
       print ("Press M to go to main menu")
```

I added the code from below to some of the code. Know when I run it I get an error saying inconstant use of space of tabs and highlight the end of the line saying:

```
  print ("Mage: Weak at close combat")
```

why is there are not space after the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put all of the above code inside a `while True:` loop, and `break` out of the loop when you don't want to return to the main menu.

```
while True:
    # your code here
    return_to_menu = input()
    if return_to_menu != 'M':
        break
```

On a side note, I'd perhaps use `else if`s. They are a tad faster because when one of the conditions matches, the others in the `if`...`else if` block are not evaluated.

Comment: I added your code and know get an error I added it ito the question

Comment: @dashernasher: Look at the line after the highlighted one. Is it indented at the same level as the highlighted line? (Does it have as many spaces/tabs in front?) Also: Choose either spaces or tabs, and then consistently use your choice for indentation throughout the entire file.

Answer (score 2):

When I run this, I get:

```
...        print ("Mage: Weak at close combat")
...  print ("      Good at long range combat")
  File "<stdin>", line 51
    print ("      Good at long range combat")
                                            ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Check the "Good at long range combat" line - it appears to have a tab instead of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("Soldier. Press S for more info")
print ("Archer. Press A for more info")
print ("Mage. Press M for more info")
print ("Changeling. Press C for more info")
print ("Rouge. Press R for more info")
print ("Press M to go to main menu")
```

So M is both for Mage and Menu. Whoops.